# Why the VisualStudio Closing when i write this Wpf xmal code

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

i have written a code in wpf to show the Exponential , by accepting the two numbers
for that i have created one converter function and code..
but when after writing this code it showing error like
"Microsoft Visual Studio encountered a problem and it has to Closed"..then when we click on Don't send it closes the Vs2010.
What might be the problem for that? the code is attached here...

```
namespace WpfTutSamples
{

    public partial class Exponential : Window
    {
        public Exponential()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public double GetValue(double number, double exponent)
        {
            double value = Math.Pow(number, exponent);
            return value;

        }
    }
}
```

> -----XmlCode

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutSamples.Exponential"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTutSamples"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Exponential" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="expCalculator" MethodName="GetValue" ObjectType="{x:Type local:Exponential}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <sys:Double>4</sys:Double>
                <sys:Double>2</sys:Double>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>

        <Label Content="Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2"> </Label>

        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtNumber" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="70,1" Width="60"
                 Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource expCalculator}, Path=MethodParametes[0], Mode=OneWayToSource, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"></TextBox>


        <Label Content="Number" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,40"> </Label>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtpower" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="70,40" Width="60"
                 Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource expCalculator}, Path=MethodParametes[1], Mode=OneWayToSource, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"></TextBox>


<Label Content="Result" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="2,80"> </Label>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="txtResult" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="70,80" Width="60"
                 Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource expCalculator}}"></TextBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What happens when you reopen the VS?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

Maybe because of stackoverflow? You reference `Exponential` class' method from `Exponential` class' `ObjectDataProvider`, which creates `Exponential` class instance, which instantiates `ObjectDataProvider` and so on.

**Explanation**

`ObjectDataProvider` binding to a method needs to instantiate class, containing that method to invoke it. That's why you have endless recurrence.

**Workaround**

Place method in a separate class and refer it by `ObjectDataProvider` in Exponential.xaml

Comment: Agree, I've had VS crashes due to a stack overflow.

Comment: Yeah, VS xaml designer doesn't handle it